# Missing data in Redshift Update after INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

The goal is to upsert data from **original_table** into the **target** table using **stage** temp table. Upserting works fine. The problem I'm having is that after upserting I'd like to modify versions timestamps in the target but only for *id*s that were in the stagged table.

Queries below is roughly what I have. When removing the `WHERE` from the last update, i.e `WHERE t.id in (SELECT DISTINCT id from stage)` all works as intended. However, we're expecting billions of rows so doing this every couple of hours is not feasible. (Yes, subquery will be changed into INNER JOIN to optimize performance.)

Any idea what's going on? Why there are no rows in the *target* with *id* (in stage) even though I just copied over that table?

```sql
-- Temp table
CREATE TEMP TABLE stage (LIKE target);

-- Lift recent data from one table and put it into stage
INSERT INTO stage SELECT {transformations} FROM original_table WHERE version_start > current_day - 1;

-- Update overlaps in the stage table with ids that are in target
UPDATE stage
SET id = target.id
FROM target WHERE stage.service_id = target.service_id AND stage.region = target.region;

-- Update unique row_id (per id and version)
UPDATE stage
SET row_id = target.row_id
FROM target WHERE stage.id = target.id AND stage.timestamp_start = target.timestamp_start;

-- Delete all duplicate entries
DELETE FROM target USING stage WHERE stage.row_id = target.row_id;

-- Copy over all staged data into cleaned target
INSERT INTO target SELECT * FROM stage s;

-- Update entries in the 'target' to have {current_row}.version_start = {previous_row}.version_end.
-- Look only for ids that were in the stage table.
UPDATE target
SET timestamp_end = versions.timestamp_end
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.row_id, t.id, t.timestamp_start,
        lead(t.timestamp_start) over (partition by t.id order by t.timestamp_start asc) as timestamp_end
    FROM target t
    WHERE t.id in (SELECT DISTINCT id from stage)
) versions
WHERE target.row_id = versions.row_id;
```

Comment: How exactly theses statements are executed? Is it within same transaction or there is commit performed after each statement?

Comment: There are all in the same transaction.

Comment: Is there the same behavior if you use normal table instead of TEMP table?